# Bash - array element exists

Tags: bash

I'm trying to see if first argument exists in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

action="$1"
actions=( install run )
actionOK=false

for i in "${actions[@]}"
do
    if [ $i=$action ]; then
        actionOK=true
    fi
done

echo $actionOK

if [ $actionOK = false ]; then
    echo "unknown action: $action"
fi
```

now when trying `wan27 run`, the script echoes true, but it also echoes true for an action that is not in array, such as test, foo, bar or whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your script was working for "install", but not "run".

You need to do:

```
for i in "${actions[@]}"
do
  ...
done
```

This is because `$actions` expands to only the first element of the array.

```
$ array=( a b c )
$ echo $array
a
$ echo "${array[@]}"
a b c
```

See the [bash arrays documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) for more details about how arrays work.

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell's filename expansion operators. If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array name.

Comment: thanks for the update! yet it still outputs true whether the action is in array or not :(

Comment: Then you've got another bug somewhere else.  Is that the whole code or is there more?  Are there any errors?  Maybe you need to change the first line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: I'll update my question to post the all code

Comment: Are you sure that is the script you are running?  Are you typing `wan27` or `./wan27`?  What does `type wan27` say?

Comment: Hang on.  `[ $i=$action ]` needs to have spaces like this: `[ $i = $action ]`.  Your original post had spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the corrected script by François Vespa and it works for me ok, it outputs "unknown action: ..." if I pass something else than run or install.

The only error I see is when I don't pass any argument. You should check for [ $# -gt 0 ] or [ $# -eq 1 ] to find out if arguments were passed at all.

Comment: The problem was the missing spaces in `[ $i=$action ]`.  Every part between `[` and `]` needs to be separated by spaces, because `[` is a command that takes three arguments when using `=`.